# How do you job search for roles that include R in the job description?

Tags: job-search, new-job, job-description

I've been job searching recently, and I'm running into a problem I've had the past few years. If I'm on say, Indeed's job search, it's pretty easy to search for jobs that include words like "SQL" and "Python" because there's no way the search can confuse those terms with something else. When searching for R, I'm having a lot of trouble because it's just one letter.

Anyone have any suggestions on how I can narrow my search to include jobs that list R in the description?

Comment: Depending on the job board, R will be available as a tag.

For example on Stack Overflow:
https://stackoverflow.com/jobs/developer-jobs-using-r?id=384449

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunately, none of the primary job boards I search offer that option.

Comment: Can you search for 'R ' (with the space, and possibly with the quotes)?

Comment: Include a second term to narrow down the results. Something like `R data science site:lever.co` returns very relevant results.

Answer (score 4):

**Try common package names or things like “RStudio”**

Job descriptions rarely have just the programming language. They also have the tools you will use and the frameworks and packages which are frequently used there.

Comment: Interesting. In my years of job searching I'm not sure I've ever seen a package listed in the job description. I see it occasionally for Python (usually it will list pandas and a few other), but never for R. Here's an example from Indeed: https://www.indeed.com/jobs?as_and=&as_phr=&as_any=dplyr+tidyverse+devtools+ggplot&as_not=&as_ttl=&as_cmp=&jt=all&st=&as_src=&salary=&radius=25&l=&fromage=any&limit=10&sort=date&psf=advsrch&from=advancedsearch

Most job descriptions will say something like:

`Knowledge of SQL, R and Python, and/or other programming languages.`

Comment: @gooponyagrinch Please [do not use backquotes to highlight quoted text](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/135112/) in comments. This syntax should be reserved for code or data, not normal text. Abusing code markdown has ugly results, [causes problems](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/7437) for parsing tools such as screen readers for the visually impaired, and is easily avoided by using italics and quotation marks instead.

Answer (score 1):

I did a quick look at some of the jobs posted using the above methods on Stack Overflow and Indeed (**quick and non-scientific**). My conclusions:

1. This works well on Indeed.
2. The 'R' tag on Stack Overflow brought up mostly jobs with Python in the title, and I found no mention of R within the bodies of the job postings.

I do appreciate the methods outlined, and will set up filters for my job search!